# Хочу реализовать интеграцию Битрикс с API

Tags: php, битрикс

Хочу реализовать интеграцию Битрикс с API.
Реализацию которой не нашел в marketplace.

Можно ли обойтись созданием компонента или нужно писать модуль?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря для каких целей вам это необходимо, если вы собираетесь распространять свое API через marketplace то модуль однозначно а если просто для себя или какой то одноразовой задачи то можете написать компонент и использовать, если вы не знали то компоненты написанные на d7 можно подключать через `CBitrixComponent::includeComponentClass("test:test.api");` так как у нас на d7 компонент это класс то можно использовать его методы и свойства в своем коде просто подключив, ну или писать модуль и подключать как обычно `CModule::IncludeModule("test.api");` или на d7 
`use Bitrix\Main\Loader;
Loader::includeModule("test.api");`